# "Incorrect SQLSTATE given to is_truncated_warning." using PHP with SQLSRV in Debian Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, connection-pooling, sqlsrv

I am using Microsoft's ODBC Driver (version 17) for SQL Server on a development server. With connection pooling off, the application runs unacceptable slowly. If I turn connection pooling on, the application runs much faster, but one particularly query-heavy page executes about five queries successfully, and then dies with

> PHP Fatal error:  Incorrect SQLSTATE given to is_truncated_warning

Here is my odbcinst.ini, in case that helps

```
[ODBC]
Pooling=Yes

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.0.5
UsageCount=1
CPTimeout=120
```

I have tried raising the number of connections, but it has no discernible effect.

I have tried googling for the error and read through [the issues on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues), but nobody else seems to have encountered this.

One other piece of information that might help: the application works fine (fast, uses pooling) using PHP5.6 and FreeTDS on IIS. I was hoping to be able to migrate to a more up-to-date version of PHP on Linux.

Comment: You can try to catch the offending query using Profiler, filter on SQLBatchStartin, Warnings, User errors

Comment: According to system requierements on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver (on date Feb 6th 2018), sqlsrv drivers require ODBC Driver version of 11 or 13, depends on PHP version. There may be inconsistences between sqlsrv drivers and version 17 ODBC Driver.

Comment: Thanks for your help, both of you. I did catch the query that was doing this. When I can replicate it more reliably I will submit a ticket to Microsoft. Version 17 is currently the preview version, so I can't expect it to be perfect, but it's the only version that works with Debian 9.

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen with this particular driver if you are retrieving fields which are more than 256 characters in length. There are two ways to get around it:

1. Limit fields to 256 characters. This is not always practical, but sometimes people decide to do things like lumping a lot of data from different fields into one with a STUFF (( ... FOR XML PATH('')  ), 1, 1, '').
2. Avoid wrapping direct calls to the database with your own functions. I've found that I only get this problem if I have wrapped calls to functions like sqlsrv_query in my own functions, for ease of use. Calling sqlsrv_...() functions directly always seems to work.

In case it is helpful, the fatal error is always triggered by a call to sqlsrv_fetch_object().

Answer (score 0):

I was intermittently receiving this error calling PDO fetch() method.

For me the solution was to delete my vagrant virtual machine and re-creating it so maybe some corruption had occurred or a bad combination of PDO and ODBC drivers